# supabase bucket policy to insert file not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, supabase

I am trying to insert a file into a supabase public bucket, I've created basic policies to insert, select. when I try to upload a file though it returns

```
{
  statusCode: '401',
  error: 'Invalid JWT',
  message: 'new row violates row-level security policy for table "objects"'
}
```

I've coverted the file to base64 format then decoded the data during upload, could the error be anything related to this? I've tried adding multiple policies to the bucket but to no avail.
My policies for bucket include public access policies for insert, select operations. policy : `(bucket_id = 'trycoin'::text)` is there any other policy I am supposed to add?

Comment: Have you tried to create a [public access policy](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/storage#allow-public-access-to-a-bucket) to the bucket?

Comment: Yes I've tried doing that but it doesn't solve it either

Comment: Could you provide more details like source code, the policy you created or anything related? thanks.

Comment: I did not create many policies just two policy for insert and select for bucket using (bucket_id = 'trycoin'::text)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to be able to upload or download files from Supabase storage, you need to allow insert or select on the `objects` table and not the `buckets` table.

For example, if you want to allow upload(insert) in to the `trycoin` bucket, you could set a policy like this:

```sql
create policy "Allow upload on trycoin"
on storage.objects for insert
with check ( bucket_id = 'trycoin' );
```

You can find more examples on [Supabase storage docs](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/storage#allow-public-access-to-a-bucket).

Answer (score 1):

An option if you're just testing the file upload feature is disabling Row Level Security (RLS). To do this, follow these steps:

```
1). Goto table editor
2). Click on schema
3). Select the storage schema
4). Click the dropdown icon for the objects table
5). Click edit table
6). Uncheck Row Level Security (RLS)
7). And click save
```

Please be aware, Row Level Security (RLS) is recommended for production apps to improve security.

Comment: Any ideas how I can keep RLS and not get this error?

Answer (score 0):

You should also check if you spelled the bucketname **correctly** when trying to upload. It throws the same error in that case

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, so for me it was creating the right policy under storage.objects

I if you want to allow 'insert' for all, including non authenticated user, you can add a policy like this:

[Example insert policy for all in storage.object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVfCp.png)

As [dshukertjr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5458913/dshukertjr) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72878980), it is the best to check Supabase storage docs for more information.